# Concatenate row values into single row per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a problem.

**Table-1 Name : InvoiceDetail**

```
InvoiceNo      StockCode       Piece
----------     -----------     ------
1                CP-001          10
1                CP-002          15
2                CP-001          18
2                MN-001          18
```

**Table-2 Name : Stock**

```
StockCode       StockName
-----------     -----------
CP-001          Computer-A
CP-002          Computer-B
MN-001          Monitor-A
```

**Expected Result**

```
InvoiceNo      Description                   TotalPiece
----------     -----------------------       ----------
1              Computer-A, Computer-B            25
2              Computer-A, Monitor-A             36
```

I wrote the below query

**Query**

```
SELECT InvoiceNo, 
       (select StockName + '-' from Stock
    where StockCode = Results.StockCode
    order by StockName 
    FOR XML PATH('')) AS Description,
    SUM(Piece) AS TotalPiece
FROM InvoiceDetail Results
GROUP BY InvoiceNo, Results.StockCode
ORDER BY InvoiceNo
```

And results

```
InvoiceNo   Description TotalPiece
1           Computer-A- 10
1           Computer-B- 15
2           Computer-A- 18
2           Monitor-A-  18
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I prefer the current result!

Answer (score 1):

Perform the `group by` separately in a CTE, and then you can safely concatenate the description as a separate step:

```
with InvoiceGroupings as (
  select t.InvoiceNo,
         sum(t.Piece) as TotalPiece
    from InvoiceDetail t
   group by t.InvoiceNo)
select g.InvoiceNo,
       stuff((select ', ' + s.StockName
               from InvoiceDetail i
               join Stock s
                 on i.StockCode = s.StockCode
              where i.InvoiceNo = g.InvoiceNo
              order by s.StockName
                for xml path('')),1,2,'') as Description,
       g.TotalPiece
  from InvoiceGroupings g
 order by g.InvoiceNo
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdbde/1)